# Restocking my house

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible (or does it happen automatically) to restock the stuff in my house? I bought the Solitude house with alchemy table and took all the ingredients around. Is there a way to get them there again?

Thanks

Comment: Other than trying to drop them in place from your inventory, I see no other way to restock the house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In past games they've never restocked themselves, I'm also assuming this is the case here also. I've got no hard evidence of it, but at the same time, logically it isn't a shop and you've bought a house/upgrades with contents already in it as part of that package. Why should it restock unless you bought another upgrade or put items inside chests yourself/dropped items in your house? Or if an anti-thief walked in and basically decided "I know! I'll place items in this dude's house and make it look REALLY cool!" which isn't going to happen :). Does this make sense? :)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to automatically restock it, no. That's why I mainly asked if it was possible to somehow restock it (i.e. buy a refill-upgrade from the house seller etc.)

Comment: A smart thief asks "*Can you refill the house so I can steal even more stuff?*"

Comment: Good point. I never thought of it that way. Well from what I remember there's never been a way to do that, it might be a new feature in Skyrim though :).